# Is there a way to shorten dataframe name references?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When working with Pandas dataframes, I often run into long chains of operations. Like this:

```
df_movement["speed"] = df_movement["distance"] / df_movement["time"]
df_movement["estimated_time"] = df_movement["target_distance"] / df_movement["speed"]
```

And so on. I have to keep writing df_movement[whatever] dozens of times.

Is there a way to shorten this, so I don't have to keep writing the "df_movement" part over and over again? Some way to use a with statement on a dataframe?

Comment: `d = df_movement`...!? Long names should not be a problem if you use a proper IDE.

Comment: IDE is one way to go, it's just I find it kind of annoying to have to reference the dataframe over and over and over again and then look at all those repetitions. Coding OCD  :D

Comment: Get used to it, having bad names is far worse, that is not "OCD :D", is just just bad manners, bad code style and bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't say that it's much better to read or shorter to write, but if you prefer you can do the same in just one call to [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), especially if you have a lot of new columns to create:

```
df_movement = df_movement.assign(speed = lambda x: x.distance/x.time,
                                 estimated_time = lambda x: x.target_distance/x.speed)
```